# Display values of variable inside another variable in the body of E-mail

Tags: mysql, database, powershell

```
--Connect and open MYSQL Connection to the database
$strUser = "X"
$strPW = "Y"
$strDB = "Z"
$strserver = "dataserver"

[void][System.Reflection.ASsembly]::LoadWithPartialName("MySql.Data")
$conn = New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection
$cs = "server=$($strserver);port=3306;database=$($strdb);uid=$($struser);pwd=$($strPW)"
$conn.connectionstring = $cs
$conn.Open()

$query = "select * from users"


$cmd = new-object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand($StoresNotPolledToday,$conn)
$da = new-object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataAdapter($cmd)
$ds = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$recordcount = $da.Fill($ds, "users")

--Display the values from the query
$ds.Tables



-- Compile the e-mail
$From = "test@gmail.com"
[string[]]$To = "Me@gmail.com"
$Subject = "Test Subject"
$Body = "Test Body and text
$ds.Tables "

$SMTPServer = "smtp.gmail.com"
$SMTPPort = "587"
$password = "Password1" | ConvertTo-SecureString -asPlainText -Force
$username = "test@gmail.com"
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($username,$password)
Send-MailMessage -From $From -to $To -Subject $Subject `
-Body $Body -SmtpServer $SMTPServer -port $SMTPPort -UseSsl `
-Credential $credential
```

Final result in the body of the e-mail which i am receiving is: "System.Data.DataSet"
How can i force it to display the values from the $ds.Tables inside the body of the e-mail?

I have tried with:

```
$var = $ds.Tables
```

and then to put this $var in the $body of the e-mail

```
$Body = "Test Body and text
    $var "
```

The result that i received in the body was: "users" as Body

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have mysql db to test against but you need to convert $ds.tables to an object that can be converted to at least an HTML fragment if not, just to an entire HTML page:

```
$ds.tables | Convertto-HTML
```

or

```
$ds.tables | Convertto-Html -Fragment
```

if that doesn't properly show the data accurately (PowerShell would be doing a lot of data conversions on your behalf if it does), you need to take the .Tables Collection object and convert it to an object that can be converted to an HTML fragment:

I commonly do this type of work by converting the base Collection object to an array first and then perform the conversion

```
@($ds.tables) | Covnertto-Html
```

Edit 1:

Also, on your Send-MailMessage cmdlet, you're going to want to use the property, -BodyAsHtml $true

Edit 2:

Here are the edits, more clearly, that I was suggesting:

```
$arr = @($ds.Tables)  ## Have PowerShell change the type from a probably SqlDataTable to an Array



-- Compile the e-mail
$From = "test@gmail.com"
[string[]]$To = "Me@gmail.com"
$Subject = "Test Subject"
$Body = ($arr | ConvertTo-Html)  ## Convert to the array to an HTML page
$SMTPServer = "smtp.gmail.com"
$SMTPPort = "587"
$password = "Password1" | ConvertTo-SecureString -asPlainText -Force
$username = "test@gmail.com"
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($username,$password)
Send-MailMessage -From $From -to $To -Subject $Subject -BodyAsHtml $true ` ## Added the flag to allow the email to be sent in HTML format
-Body $Body -SmtpServer $SMTPServer -port $SMTPPort -UseSsl `
-Credential $credential
```

Comment: Is this how it should look like? Error:param.cant be found accepts argt 'true''

$ds.tables | Convertto-HTML 
--Compile the email:
$Subject = "Test Subject"
$Body = "Test Body
$ds.Tables "

$SMTPServer = "smtp.gmail.com"
$SMTPPort = "587"
$password = "Password1" | ConvertTo-SecureString -asPlainText -Force
$username = "test@gmail.com"
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($username,$password)
Send-MailMessage -From $From -to $To -Subject $Subject `
-Body $Body -BodyAsHtml $true -SmtpServer $SMTPServer -port $SMTPPort -UseSsl `
-Credential $credential

Comment: @AtanasS. Try the changes in Edit 2

Comment: This is showing me "The email cannot be sent because no SMTP server was specified" and also "The term '-Body' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet" Anyway I managed to put the variable in txt file and then insert the .txt file in the body as 
  $arr = @($ds.Tables)

  write-output $arr | out-file -filepath C:\test.txt
Then in the body:

  $Body = [IO.File]::ReadAllText("C:\test.txt")

This worked for me. THANK YOU

Comment: It's  because of my comment I added after your line-wrapping back-tick.  Remove my comments and you'll be good--my comments were the ones with the double hash tag (##).